# Euclid's Parallel Postulate Proof

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, math-history

I was checking this page: http://math2.org/math/misc/unproved.htm

And `Euclid's Parallel Postulate` caught my interest. However, I don't fully seem to understand it... What are we required to prove? That the orange & blue lines are parallel or what?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUv0U.png)

Or do we have to prove that **only a single line** (orange one) is parallel to the blue line?

Comment: According to the linked site, indeed you need to prove that there is only one orange line going through that point which is parallel to the blue line.

Comment: Wouldn't building random lines that are intercepted by the dot (on the orange line), all (except that parallel one) intercept the blue line, and therefore would mean that they are not parallel to each other, so that would mean that one line drawn (orange) which never intercepts the other line (blue) would mean they are parallel? (Let me know if you want me to draw this to help you understand)

Comment: (Doesn't let me edit, but here: http://i.imgur.com/QeowDHL.png )

Answer (score 4):

This can't be proven. Many people in the past have tried to prove that it's true that (1) there always exists a line parallel to another line through a point and that (2) it is unique. The only meaningful proof would be something axiomatic, using the other four of Euclid's postulates:

1. A straight line segment can be drawn joining any two points.
2. Any straight line segment can be extended indefinitely in a straight line.
3. Given any straight line segment, a circle can be drawn having the segment as radius and one endpoint as centre.
4. All right angles are congruent.

However, the parallel postulate has been shown to be independent of these. If you include it as an axiom, you get "Euclidean Geometry" which is basically all of the geometry you learn until the end of high school. If you do not include the parallel postulate (or use other axioms, like "every line intersects every other line exactly once") you end up with many other "geometries". You should look into hyperbolic and elliptic geometry!

Comment: To make things clearer for the OP: avoid that site!

Comment: Could you pleaseprovide any references, where it has been shown that the parallel postulate is independent of other 4?